# regex with quotes, equal sign and dot for attribute/value pair

Tags: python, regex

I need help with parsing user input in python using a mixture of regex and iterating over the result from the regex. An example input looks like this:

```
KeylessBuy=f and not (Feedback.color = green or comment.color=green) 
and not "BIN State".color = white and comment="got it right"
```

The split result should be:

```
KeylessBuy=f
Feedback.color = green
comment.color=green
"BIN State".color = white
comment="got it right"
```

So picking only those parts that directly surround the "="-sign. I tried (among others):

```
    r'(\w+\s{0,}(?<!=)={1,2}(?!=)\s{0,}\w+)'
    r'|("(.*?)"\s{0,}(?<!=)={1,2}(?!=)\s{0,}\w+)'
    r'|("(.*?)"\s{0,}(?<!=)={1,2}(?!=)\s{0,}"(.*?)")'
    r'|(\w+\s{0,}(?<!=)={1,2}(?!=)\s{0,}"(.*?)")'
    r'|(\w+\s{0,}\.\w+\s{0,}(?<!=)={1,2}(?!=)\s{0,}"(.*?)")',
```

This only "almost" gives the right answer.
Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks indeed. Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''KeylessBuy=f and not (Feedback.color = green or comment.color=green) 
and not "BIN State".color = white and comment="got it right"'''
>>> m = re.findall(r'(?:[\w.]+|"[^=]*)\s*=\s*(?:\w+|"[^"]*")', s)
>>> for x in m:
...     print x

KeylessBuy=f
Feedback.color = green
comment.color=green
"BIN State".color = white
comment="got it right"
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it to match what you're looking for using

```
((?:"[^"]+")?[\w\.]+?) ?= ?((?:"[^"]+")|\w+)
```

You can view the regex demo [here](http://regex101.com/r/vC2qV1/1)

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Get the matched group from index 1.

```
((\"[^=]*|[\w\.]+)\s*=\s*(\w+|\"[^"]*\"))
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rS3aG4/9)

Sample code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'((\"[^=]*|[\w\.]+)\s*=\s*(\w+|\"[^"]*\"))')
test_str = u"KeylessBuy=f and not (Feedback.color = green or comment.color=green) \nand not \"BIN State\".color = white and comment=\"got it right\""

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below regex,

```
>>> str = '''
... KeylessBuy=f and not (Feedback.color = green or comment.color=green) 
... and not "BIN State".color = white and comment="got it right"'''
>>> m = re.findall(r'(?:\"[\w ]+\")?[\w.]+\s*=\s*(?:\w+)?(?:\"[\w ]+\")?', str)
>>> m
['KeylessBuy=f', 'Feedback.color = green', 'comment.color=green', '"BIN State".color = white', 'comment="got it right"']
>>> for item in m:
...     print item
... 
KeylessBuy=f
Feedback.color = green
comment.color=green
"BIN State".color = white
comment="got it right"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vV8uQ3/10)

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight now updated. Sorry, slow internet connection...:(